# NSURLConnection cache persistance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, caching

In iOS 5, my NSURLConnection cache gets blown away if my app is terminated. How do I persist the NSURLConnection cache even after my app gets terminated and started fresh again? Caching works great as long as my app stays alive.

I am using `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` in my NSURLRequest.

Sample header returned by my server:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600
Content-Encoding:deflate
Content-Length:1606
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 16 Sep 2012 20:22:14 GMT
Expires:Sun, 16 Sep 2012 21:22:15 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 16 Sep 2012 20:22:15 GMT
Vary:*
```

If my app is terminated after 5 minutes and I restart, a full fresh download is attempted (verified with Charles http listener)...

Comment: Among other things, that depends on the caching headers set by the remote service (server). Make sure you quote a relevant one for better help.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question - indeed your server is asking for proper caching throughout the period of one hour. Now what you need is disk-caching and that has been disabled prior to iOS5 (if I recall correctly). Make sure you read to following, excellent article on that issue: [nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5/)

Comment: So in iOS 5+ do I need the extra code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a result of me not setting the disk cache size. Setting it to 500MB seems to now persist my cache even if the app is terminated.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem. Setting the diskCapacity like this made the caching work even the app is terminated and restarted: 

`NSURLCache *cache = [NSURLCache sharedURLCache];
    /* 50 MB Cache */
    [cache setDiskCapacity:1024*1024*50];`

Comment: I've got a mediocre 12 MB cache and it doesn't seem to be using it at all.  Any experience with that issue?

Comment: What's in your http headers in your response?